# Passing and unwrapping Observable as Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables

I need to pass data from one component to another but I'm having a hard time doing so.

I have an `Observable` that I need to pass as `Subject` which is another Observable. How do I do that?
The way I currently have is not working as it gets in the *target component* `undefined`.

This is what I have:

**card.component.ts** *(where it all begins)*

```
showBox(studentID) {
    const airportPickup = this.studentService.getCurrentStudents().pipe(
        map(snaps => {
            const student = snaps.find( s => s.studentID === studentID );
            return {
                requirePickup: student.pickup,
                whopickup: student.whoPickup
            };
        })
    );
    this.studentService.airportPickupDropoff.next(airportPickup);
}
```

If I `console.log()` the `airportPickup` I get the object. No issues. The problem is when I get it in the other component, I get it as `undefined`.

**flight-info.component.ts** *(the target)*

```
getAirportPickup() {
    this.studentService.airportPickupDropoff.subscribe(
        (apdata) => {
            this.airportPickupDropoff = apdata;
        },
        (e) => alert(e)
    );
}
```

The **service** I have this:

`airportPickupDropoff = new Subject<any>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to subscribe to the observable, or chain it with RxJS operators(such as [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap)), in order to assign the values from the observable into your `airportPickupDropoff`  Subject.

Option 1:

```
showBox(studentID) {
  this.studentService.getCurrentStudents().pipe(
    map(snaps => {
      const student = snaps.find( s => s.studentID === studentID );
      return {
        requirePickup: student.pickup,
        whopickup: student.whoPickup
      };
    }),
  ).subscribe(response => {
    this.studentService.airportPickupDropoff.next(response);
  });
}
```

Option 2:

```
showBox(studentID) {
  this.studentService.getCurrentStudents().pipe(
    map(snaps => {
      const student = snaps.find( s => s.studentID === studentID );
      return {
        requirePickup: student.pickup,
        whopickup: student.whoPickup
      };
    }),
    tap(response => this.studentService.airportPickupDropoff.next(response)),
  ).subscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe would be better to send data via `Subject` instead of another `Observable`?

```
showBox(studentID) {
  ///...
  airportPickup.subscribe(apdata => this.studentService.airportPickupDropoff.next(apdata));
}
```